# Determine if the given set is a complex vector space.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

The set of all vectors in $\mathbb C^2$ of the form $(z, \overline{z})$ with the usual vector addition and scale multiplication.

Ran into this problem while studying for a test. How would I solve it?

Comment: I got all axioms to pass. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** If you add two vectors of this form, is the result also of this form? What about multiplying a vector of this form by a complex scalar? What are the requirements for a set to he a vector space?